# Listbox filtering using a texbox

Tags: asp.net

My need is that.I have a listbox with datafrom a database.there is a textbox for search.when I write something on a textbox listboxdata item must be selected based on that data?
ex:

if listbox contain Bat,Cat,Rat
when I type b on textbox Bat mustbe selected..

This is for asp.net webform

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

- If you already have a listbox that is binded into a dataTable, you can use binding source.

Place this in the text change event...

```
YourBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("columnName LIKE '{0}%'", txtFilter.Text)
```

- Or you can use Javascript/JQuery for listbox content manipulation on the client side. There are tons of examples out there such as:

https://sites.google.com/site/saneparakrishna/jquery/filter-a-listbox-with-textbox-using-jquery

Comment: @user3507790 Glad to help! If this answer helped you out, consider accepting it.

Comment: Is any other link for autocomplete textbox,livesearch dropdownlist in asp.net